# Best way to regroup a string into a list of 2-character string

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string 0xb1ca2a3e4fac which is a MAC address.
Now I'm hoping to make it into a list of

```
['b1','ca','2a','3e','4f','ac']
```

Though I can do it in a for-loop or some similar way,
I hope for a splendid pythonic way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data = "0xb1ca2a3e4fac"[2:]
```

1. Using [`textwrap.wrap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap)

   ```
   import textwrap
   print textwrap.wrap(data[2:], 2)
   ```
2. Using List comprehension

   ```
   print [data[i:i+2] for i in xrange(0, len(data), 2)]
   ```
3. Using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

   ```
   print map("".join, zip(*[iter(data)] * 2))
   ```

**Output**

```
['b1', 'ca', '2a', '3e', '4f', 'ac']
```